# While running shell script directly from artifactory is not taking input

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a shell script where I am executing

```
read -p "Enter realm[comm|ukg]:" REALM
```

to get the input for `REALM` from the user. It is working fine when i am executing locally. But when i am trying to execute this from Artifactory it is not prompting for user input.

The command which I am using is

```
curl -sL https://example.com/fsre-mw-dev-generic-local/fapodlookup_fido_changes_1.sh |
bash -s
```

or

```
curl -sL https://example.com/fsre-mw-dev-generic-local/fapodlookup_fido_changes_1.sh |
bash -s <REALM_VALUE>
```

but in both cases it is not working. I have tried different things as well.

First try:

```
REALM=${1:-}
if [[ -z "$REALM" ]]; then
    read -p "Enter realm[comm|ukg]:" REALM
fi
```

Second try:

```
# Read realm from interactive input or command-line argument
if [[ -z "$REALM" ]]; then
    read -p "Enter realm[comm|ukg]:" REALM
elif [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
    REALM=$1
fi
```

Third try:

```
# Read realm from interactive input or command-line argument
if [[ -z "$REALM" && -z "$1" ]]; then
    read -p "Enter realm[comm|ukg]:" REALM
elif [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
    REALM=$1
fi
```

Fourth try:

```
# Read realm from interactive input or command-line argument
REALM=${1:-}

if [[ -z "$REALM" ]]; then
    # Check if running interactively before prompting
    if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
        read -p "Enter realm[comm|ukg]:" REALM
    fi
fi

if [[ -z "$REALM" ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Realm comm or ukg needs to be provided."
    exit 1
fi
```

Please help me either pass the realm value using `curl` command to shell script, or is there a way I can get the prompt to enter realm whenever I try to execute via `curl`?

Comment: Think about how `curl | bash` works. You tied your stdin to curl, so that's where `read` gets data from.

Comment: If you want to read _from the user_, you can try using `read realm </dev/tty`, but that of course only works _if a TTY is available_. I'd suggest bailing with an explicit error instructing the user to pass configuration as command-line arguments (so the value is there in `$1` and the `read` never gets called) when one isn't.

Comment: The following works as I expect: `echo 'if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then read realm; else realm=$1; fi; echo "$realm"' | bash -s poo` to set `realm` to `poo` without any user interaction.

Comment: (btw, notice both tripleee and I using lower-case `$realm` in our examples above -- that's because all-caps variables are in namespace used for values meaningful to the shell and operating system, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use).

Comment: (Perhaps see also [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization))

Comment: (the `[[ -t 0 ]]` test is on the right track -- checking if stdin is attached to a TTY -- but when stdin is attached to curl, of course, it _isn't_ attached to a TTY so that check is expected to fail; that doesn't mean your process doesn't a controlling TTY assigned, though, so it doesn't guarantee to you that opening `/dev/tty` will fail).

Comment: (removed the sh tag since you're using a _lot_ of non-POSIX extensions in your question)